# JSONP dataType when XML is returned

Tags: ajax, jsonp

I'm playing around with JSONP.  I understand (maybe) the concept but am a little backwards on the implementation.

What I have is a web server that, from a URL string, produces an XML result.  As I've researched, JSONP is supposed to work around the cross-domain issue, but the expected return data is still a JSON array.  So if the server is returning XML, how do I get my ajax script to recognize that and be able to parse it?

Here's my code:

```
var usdaurl = 'http://eligibility.sc.egov.usda.gov/eligibility/eligibilityservice?eligibilityType=Property&requestString=<?xml version="1.0"?><Eligibility xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="/var/lib/tomcat5/webapps/eligibility/Eligibilitywsdl.xsd"><PropertyRequest StreetAddress1="'+street+'" StreetAddress2="" StreetAddress3="" City="'+city+'" State="'+state+'" County="" Zip="'+zip+'" Program="RBS"></PropertyRequest></Eligibility>';
var clbk = function(xml){
          var usda = $('Property').attr('Eligibility');
       };

$.ajax({
    url: usdaurl,
    dataType: 'jsonp',
    jsonpCallback: 'clbk'
});
```

Also, the error I get is an un recognized character from the XML responce.

```
Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token <
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`jsonp` has to be supported by the service you are requesting from, otherwise [SOP](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Same_origin_policy_for_JavaScript) would be totally useless. There is this misconception that if you want to make a cross origin request you just use jsonp. `jsonp`(also [CORS](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/HTTP/Access_control_CORS)) is a method for providers to allow users to get their content without the SOP restriction, its not a way for anyone to just by pass Same origin policy.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up a proxy to stringize the xml/html/soap/whatever and wrap it in a callback.

Here is an example using a cgi shell script (I have it always gzipping the output since 99.9% of browsers that support javascript also support gzip)

```
#!/bin/sh
CB=${QUERY_STRING%%&*}
URL=${QUERY_STRING#*&}
case "$CB" in
    callback=*)
        printf "Content-Encoding: gzip\nContent-type: application/javascript\r\n\r\n"
        while ([ ! "$ONCE" ])   do
            printf "${CB##*=}(\""
            wget --no-check-certificate -U "NetSurf/2.9 (Linux; i686)" -T 20 -O - "$URL" \
                | tr -c [\ -~] " " |sed 's/[\]/\\\\/g;s/["]/\\"/g'
            printf "\")"
            ONCE=1
        done | gzip -9fc
    ;;
    *)exit;;
esac
```

Here is an example usage assuming your server is at localhost and the script is in /cgi-bin/xml2jsonpgz.cgi (typical location for busybox's httpd)  It uses the returned string in a callback to wedge the whole uri into a `<div>` tag, but you could then it to get at the DOM to do what you want.

```
<html><head><title>test</title></head><body><div id="notaniframe"></div>
<script>
    function dummy(data){alert(data);document.getElementById("notaniframe").innerHTML=data}
    Loaded=0
    setTimeout(function(){if(!Loaded)alert("load failed")},30000);
</script>
<script onload='Loaded=1;alert("loaded")' src="http://localhost/cgi-bin/xml2jsonpgz.cgi?callback=dummy&http://stackoverflow.com"></script>
</body></html>
```

Basic usage is: set the src=urlOfCgiScript+"?callback="+callBackName+"&"+url
and set up the callback to handle the string.

You can do the same thing with json data, but with less complicated escaping.